# Move the cursor to a new line in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am facing an issue with Word VBA,
Actually in a Word document, I want to move the cursor to a new line,

I tried 2 instructions but it didn't work,

The first instruction: `Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf`

The second code block:

```
Set lastParagraph = Selection.Paragraphs(Selection.Paragraphs.Count)
lastParagraph.range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
```

Both instructions didn't help to move the cursor to a new line

I would apperciate your help, Thanks in advance!

Comment: When coding in VBA it is advisable to avoid moving the cursor. This prevents a lot of screen redrawing which slows down execution. If you really must move the cursor, why don't you simply record a macro?

Comment: Pls. try `ActiveDocument.Range(ActiveDocument.Content.End - 1).Select`

Comment: Or, more simply, `ActiveDocument.Characters.Last.Select`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The insert does not change the cursor position and this is good so.
But if you need to move the cursor for your both example try

```
 Sub one()
    Selection.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    Selection.Move wdParagraph, 1
    End Sub
    
    Sub two()
    Dim lastParagraph As Paragraph
    Set lastParagraph = Selection.Paragraphs(Selection.Paragraphs.Count)
    lastParagraph.Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf
    Selection.Move wdParagraph, 1
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this solution helps to move the cursor to a new line!